# What are iterated cobar constructions?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

In Beck's paper "On H-spaces and Infinite Loop Spaces", he states that every algebra over the monad $\Omega^k$$\Sigma^k$ is a $k$-fold loop space. He proves the trivial case k = 0 when this is the identity monad, and says the remaining cases follow from "iterated cobar constructions". I'm hoping someone can elaborate on what exactly is meant by this statement.

Comment: I think p. 21 of http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/uicc/drachman.pdf might be relevant. It's a very brief section, but is related to the question.

Comment: Thanks! I will look that over. It does indeed seem relevant.

Comment: A modern treatment of this is also in section 5.2.3 of http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/higheralgebra.pdf

Comment: An older reference is May's Geometry of Iterated Loop Spaces.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Part of my question is whether or not the methods May employed were the iterated cobar constructions that Beck had in mind. I would be happy to see what argument people think he had in mind for the $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is a map of mondas $D_k\longrightarrow \Omega^kS^k$ where $D_k$ is the little disks operad (see May's original lecture notes, for example), so any algebra over the target monad is one over the little disks, and hence a $k$-fold loop space.